# How do I test with chai-as-promised a rejected promise and the error message?

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner, chai, chai-as-promised

I'm trying to check the error message on a rejected promise and if I make the message string wrong in the test it still passes.

```
MyService.doSomething({ id: 12345 }).should.eventually.be.rejectedWith(TypeError, 'no attr foo defined2');



  svc.doSomething = function(thing){
    var def = $q.defer();

    if ( !thing.foo ) {
        def.reject(new Error('no attr foo defined'));
    } else {
        def.resolve(thing);
    }

    return def.promise;
  };
```

Update, it seems my tests are not working properly. When I return it times out:

```
  it.only('should error', function(){
    // todo this should fail but it just times out
    return MyService.doSomething({ id: 12345 }).should.eventually.be.rejectedWith(TypeError, 'no attr foo defined2');
  });







  svc.doSomething = function(thing){
    var def = $q.defer();

    if ( !thing.foo ) {
        def.reject(new Error('no attr foo defined'));
    } else {
        def.resolve(thing);
    }

    return def.promise;
  };
```

Here's the error:

```
Error: timeout of 4000ms exceeded. Ensure the done() callback is being called in this test.
```

Answer (score 0):

You are forgetting the eventually and the return before your call.!

```
return MyService.doSomething({ id: 12345 }).should.eventually.be.rejectedWith...
```

Comment: I tried that. Still passes if I have the string be `no attr foo defined2`

Comment: And the return before the call too!

Comment: if i add return it just times out, saying `done()` is not called.

Comment: Post your whole test code. You shouldn't be using done with chai as promised

Comment: Sorry I can't help you.  When I test server side promises with https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise  I do it just like that.

Comment: Yeah. I've narrowed it down to something wrong with `$q` -- I had to run `$scope.$apply()` in my test before testing the promise return....but now the chai-as-promised verbage doesn't work. I posted about it here if anyone knows the answer: https://github.com/domenic/chai-as-promised/issues/150